# Vue 3 using function inside setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-composition-api

I am doing a simple app and I am using mock-json-server to simulate http request.

I have defined a function to get the info I need :

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'

const getScores = () => {
const scoringPass = ref([])
const error = ref(null)

const load = async () => {
  try {
    let data = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/scores', {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    }})
    if (!data.ok) {
          throw Error('no data available')
    }
    scoringPass.value = await data.json()
    console.log(scoringPass.value)
  } catch (err) {
    error.value = err.message
    console.log(error.value)
  }
}
return { scoringPass, error, load }
}

export default getScores
```

And I call it in the setup function of my component :

```html
  <script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
    import Pass from '@/components/Pass.vue'
    import getScores from '../composables/getScores.js'

    export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
      const numeroDossier = '25020230955000004'
      const { scoringPass, error, load } = getScores()

      load()
      return { numeroDossier, scoringPass, error }
    },
    components: {
      Pass,
     },
    })
    </script>
```

In the console.log(scoringPass.value) in the function, I can see the data. but the load() function in the setup part does not work and I can't figure out why. It is called though, but I can't get the data.

When I do console.log(load()), I get :

```
Promise {<pending>}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined
```

Any help appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: How are you using the refs in the template? Could you verify that reactivity is behaving well using a watch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load()` is [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), so its return value is a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You have to `await` the call to get the underlying data. However, `load()` doesn't actually return anything, so you still wouldn't see any data. If you want `load()` to provide the initial value of `scoringPass`, `load()` should return that:

```js
const load = async () => {
  try {
    ⋮
    return scoringPass.value
  } catch (err) {
    ⋮
    return null
  }
}
```

To get the result of `load()`, you can wrap the call in an `async` function to `await` the call; or chain a [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) callback:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    ⋮
    const logLoadResults = async () => console.log(await load())
    logLoadResults()

    // or
    load().then(results => console.log(results))
  }
})
```

Don't [mark `setup()` as `async`](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/suspense.html#async-setup) because that would make your component an *async component*, requiring a `<Suspense>` in a parent component to render it.